# connection scheduling for LVS hash table

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

LVS supports a connection hash table, where a request message will firstly find out whether the connection is hashed in the LVS, and if so, the message will go to a fixed node.

LVS also supports some connection scheduling methods, like Round Robin. From the description of Round Robin, *every* request will be round-robin, which doesn't make sense to me. If the request finds an existing hashed connection, it will be delivered to a fixed node, and cannot be balanced with Round Robin.

This question confused me a lot and I cannot continue, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When IPVS receives a new connection it selects a real server to handle that connection.
That selection is done using on of the schedulers. If the connection is not new it's handed to the real server, no scheduler is used.

Round Robin is on of the schedulers that distributes all *new* connection requests round-robin and not the packets for the existing connections.